# Как найти элемент UI десктопного приложения, который не видим Inspect'у и Winium'у?

Tags: c#, winapi, ui, test-automation, uiautomation

Доброго времени суток всем читающим!

На работе поставили задачу автоматизировать тестирование UI десктопного приложения.
Автотесты пишу на C#, используя фреймворк от 2ГИСА - Winium. Для поиска элементов UI использую Inspect, которая входит в состав Windows Kits, или Winium. Так вот при поиске элементов почти сразу же столкнулся с проблемой: какие-то элементы не удается найти ни Inspect'ом, ни Winium'ом.

Вот пример одной из форм:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Inspect в данном случае не видит вкладки (выделено жёлтым), из-за чего приходится придумывать всяческие воркэраунды, вроде использования хоткеев или смещения фокуса с одного элемента на другой через табуляцию.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то способ обращаться к таким элементам?